# How to check if a response message is by the author while ignoring other messages not by the author in discord bot

Tags: discord.py

I have this

```
async def deletechar(ctx):
    em = discord.Embed(title = f"Are you sure you want to erase your character?",color = discord.Color.red())
    em.add_field(name = "Yes, delete it please",value = "Y")
    em.add_field(name = "Nevermind",value = "N")
    await ctx.send(embed = em)
    response = await client.wait_for_message('message')
    if response.content  == 'Y' and ctx.author == response.author:
        await ctx.send("Successfully Deleted Character")
    elif response.content  == 'N' and ctx.author == response.author:
        await ctx.send("Not Deleted")
```

this may be poorly written, though it works it's just that if a message is not by the author it'll kick out of the function. I want to await a response by the author within the context while ignoring other messages but not using too much CPU while doing it. Any suggestions?

I don't want it to hang in this function because I want it to be able to process messages from other users while it waits for this one

Answer (score 1):

Using a `check`

`response = await client.wait_for_message('message', check=lambda m: m.author.id == ctx.author.id)`

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly, I did some research on how lamda works in python, I guess it creates a quick little function. I don't quite understand all of the inner workings but thank you so much for this